# Python date range query

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datepicker

I am amending an existing app that queries a database and returns information from the past 7 days. I have incorporated a calendar app so one can pick their own dates to query.

The calendar is working great

```
import tkinter as Tkinter
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import ttkcalendar
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tkSimpleDialog  
from datetime import date

class CalendarDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    """Dialog box that displays a calendar and returns the selected date"""

    def body(self, master):
        self.calendar = ttkcalendar.Calendar(master)
        self.calendar.pack()

    def apply(self):
        self.result1 = self.calendar.selection
        self.result2 = self.calendar.selection

class CalendarFrame(Tkinter.LabelFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.LabelFrame.__init__(self, parent, text="Choose Dates")

    def getbegindate():
        cd = CalendarDialog(self)
        self.result1 = cd.result1
        self.Begin_date.set(self.result1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")) 

    def gettodate():
        cd = CalendarDialog(self)
        self.result2 = cd.result2
        self.To_date.set(self.result2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))

    self.Begin_date = Tkinter.StringVar()
    self.To_date = Tkinter.StringVar()

    def get_date():
        end = self.result2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        start = self.result1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        end1 = self.result2.strptime(end, "%m/%d/%Y").date()
        start1 = self.result1.strptime(start, "%m/%d/%Y").date() 
        delta = (end1 - start1).days
        daterange = [pd.date_range(start, end)]
        for single_date in daterange:
            x = single_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        rundate = x
        print(rundate) 

    Tkinter.Button(self, text="From date", command=getbegindate).grid(column=0, row=0)
    Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.Begin_date).grid(column=1, row=0)
    Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.To_date).grid(column=1, row=1)
    Tkinter.Button(self, text="To date", command=gettodate).grid(column=0, row=1)
    Tkinter.Button(self, text="SUBMIT", command=get_date).grid(column=0, columnspan=3)

def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.wm_title("Pick1")
    root.geometry("250x150+100+100")
    CalendarFrame(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The weeklyrpt still works fine when going back 7 days.

When a date range is chosen it returns "none" and returns an unpopulated screen. How do I get the dates from the calendar (Pick1.py) to populate my query

```
app_window = tk.Tk()
app_window.withdraw()

def rundate():
    result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Rundate", message="back 7 days?")
    # result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno()
    if result == True:
        rundate = date.today() - timedelta(7)
        return rundate
    else:
        os.system("pick1.py")
        def get_date():
                end = self.result2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
                start = self.result1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
                daterange = [pd.date_range(start, end)]
                for single_date in daterange:
                    x = single_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
                rundate = x
                return rundate

rundate = rundate()
print(rundate)

# Query permits made effective since rundate
query = '''select `NPDES_ID`, `EffectiveDate`, `FacilityName`, `StateFacilityID`, `City`, `CountyName`
        from Permits 
        where `EffectiveDate` >= ?
        order by `NPDES_ID`'''

IDS=[]
FacCodes=[]
PermStrings=[]
PayStrings=[]
OwnerStrings=[]
MTB=[]
MTG=[]
MTR=[]
SWC=[]
MT0=[]
count=0
# for each row in result of query
for row in cur.execute(query, (rundate, )):
    try:
        d= row[1].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    except:
        d=""
    # create a display string with the appropriate information permit # - date -  facility name - city, county
    for i in range(len(row)):
            if not row[i]:
            row[i] = ""

    permitstring=row[0]+" | "+d+"\t | "+row[2]+"\t | "+row[4]+", "+row[5]+" County"
    IDS.append(row[0])
    tempid=row[0]
    # add the index to the appropriate permit type array, used to display seperately
    if tempid[0:3]=="MTB":
        MTB.append(count)
    if tempid[0:3]=="MTG":
        MTG.append(count)
    if tempid[0:4]=="MTR0":
        MTR.append(count)
    if tempid[0:3]=="MT0" or tempid[0:3]=="MT4" or tempid[0:3]=="MTX":
        MT0.append(count)
    if tempid[0:4]=="MTR1":
        SWC.append(count)
    FacCodes.append(row[3])
    PermStrings.append(permitstring)
    count+=1
```

This is a rather large app so I hope I am including the important parts to see where I am failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repaired your code and it is working now, but I change as little as possible just to get it to work. Most of your problems are caused by wrong use of classes and object-oriented programming in general. So I don't think it would do any help if I rewrite your whole program for you, but I think you should learn OOP programming in python yourself. You can find some basics on these pages ([learnpython](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Classes_and_Objects), [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm), [introtopython](http://introtopython.org/classes.html)) or just type in google and you'll find a lot of pages, videos, courses, etc.

And here is fixed code:

```
import pick1  ## This import line you need so you can use code from that file

app_window = tk.Tk()
#app_window.withdraw()              ## we use these three lines below because we only want to hide
app_window.geometry("1x1+0+0")      ##  tkinter window temporarily and withdraw() method causes
app_window.overrideredirect(True)   ##  the window to beforgotten about by the window manager
app_window.transient()             ## more details on https://wiki.tcl.tk/3175


def rundate():
    result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Rundate", message="back 7 days?")
    #result = messagebox.askyesno(title="Rundate", message="back 7 days?")

    # result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno()
    if result == True:
        rundate = date.today() - timedelta(7)
        return rundate
    else:
        #os.system("pick1.py")
        #root = tkinter.Tk()
        app_window.wm_title("Pick1")
        app_window.geometry("250x150+100+100")
        app_window.overrideredirect(False)
        #app_window.mainloop()
        cm = pick1.CalendarFrame(app_window)
        cm.grid()
        ## here we wait until user has selected data range and
        ## and rundate has been calculated
        app_window.wait_variable(cm.wait_for_result)
        return cm.rundate

## we don't need this function because there is already same function in file pick1.py 
##        def get_date():
##            end = self.result2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
##            start = self.result1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
##            daterange = [pd.date_range(start, end)]
##            for single_date in daterange:
##                x = single_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
##            rundate = x
##            return rundate



rundate = rundate()
print(rundate)

# Query permits made effective since rundate
query = '''select `NPDES_ID`, `EffectiveDate`, `FacilityName`, `StateFacilityID`, `City`, `CountyName`
        from Permits 
        where `EffectiveDate` >= ?
        order by `NPDES_ID`'''

IDS=[]
FacCodes=[]
PermStrings=[]
PayStrings=[]
OwnerStrings=[]
MTB=[]
MTG=[]
MTR=[]
SWC=[]
MT0=[]
count=0
# for each row in result of query
for row in cur.execute(query, (rundate, )):
    try:
        d= row[1].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    except:
        d=""
    # create a display string with the appropriate information permit # - date -  facility name - city, county
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if not row[i]:
            row[i] = ""

    permitstring=row[0]+" | "+d+"\t | "+row[2]+"\t | "+row[4]+", "+row[5]+" County"
    IDS.append(row[0])
    tempid=row[0]
    # add the index to the appropriate permit type array, used to display seperately
    if tempid[0:3]=="MTB":
        MTB.append(count)
    if tempid[0:3]=="MTG":
        MTG.append(count)
    if tempid[0:4]=="MTR0":
        MTR.append(count)
    if tempid[0:3]=="MT0" or tempid[0:3]=="MT4" or tempid[0:3]=="MTX":
        MT0.append(count)
    if tempid[0:4]=="MTR1":
        SWC.append(count)
    FacCodes.append(row[3])
    PermStrings.append(permitstring)
    count+=1
```

And code for pick1.py:

```
import tkinter as Tkinter
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import ttkcalendar
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tkSimpleDialog  
from datetime import date

class CalendarDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    """Dialog box that displays a calendar and returns the selected date"""

    def body(self, master):
        self.calendar = ttkcalendar.Calendar(master)
        self.calendar.pack()

    def apply(self):
        self.result1 = self.calendar.selection
        self.result2 = self.calendar.selection

class CalendarFrame(Tkinter.LabelFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.LabelFrame.__init__(self, parent, text="Choose Dates")
        self.parent = parent
        self.Begin_date = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.To_date = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.wait_for_result = Tkinter.IntVar() ## we will use this variable to wait for user to select date range
        Tkinter.Button(self, text="From date", command=self.getbegindate).grid(column=0, row=0)
        Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.Begin_date).grid(column=1, row=0)
        Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.To_date).grid(column=1, row=1)
        Tkinter.Button(self, text="To date", command=self.gettodate).grid(column=0, row=1)
        Tkinter.Button(self, text="SUBMIT", command=self.get_date).grid(column=0, columnspan=3)


    def getbegindate(self):
        cd = CalendarDialog(self)
        self.result1 = cd.result1
        self.Begin_date.set(self.result1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")) 

    def gettodate(self):
        cd = CalendarDialog(self)
        self.result2 = cd.result2
        self.To_date.set(self.result2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))

    #self.Begin_date = Tkinter.StringVar()
    #self.To_date = Tkinter.StringVar()

    def get_date(self):
        end = self.result2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        start = self.result1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        # I commented this lines below because they don't have any use
        #end1 = self.result2.strptime(end, "%m/%d/%Y").date()
        #start1 = self.result1.strptime(start, "%m/%d/%Y").date() 
        #delta = (end1 - start1).days
        daterange = [pd.date_range(start, end)]
        for single_date in daterange:
            x = single_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        self.rundate = x
        self.wait_for_result.set(1)     # now we have result so we can set variable wait_for_result to 1
        print(self.rundate)
        self.parent.destroy()        # I added this line so tkinter window disappears once when user clicks SUBMIT button

    #Tkinter.Button(self, text="From date", command=getbegindate).grid(column=0, row=0)
    #Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.Begin_date).grid(column=1, row=0)
    #Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.To_date).grid(column=1, row=1)
    #Tkinter.Button(self, text="To date", command=gettodate).grid(column=0, row=1)
    #Tkinter.Button(self, text="SUBMIT", command=get_date).grid(column=0, columnspan=3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am, however, still getting an error - for row in cur.execute(query, (rundate, )): pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type. param-index=0 param-type=numpy.ndarray', 'HY105')

Comment: Can you tell me what is `cur`? You didn't post code where `cur` is initialized so I get `name 'cur' is not defined` error.

Comment: -@ands. Sorry, I have been out sick. The cur is at the top db = r"M:\CWA_DB\WPTS\WPTS_Prod\WPTS_PROD_be.accdb"
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq='+db)
cur = conn.cursor()

Answer (score 0):

So I got the Calendar to work using the above answer - Thank you @ands

```
result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Rundate", message="back 7 days?")
if result == True:
    start = date.today()
    end = date.today() - timedelta(7)
    daterange = [pd.date_range(start, end)]
    for single_date in daterange:
        x = single_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    rundate = x
    print(rundate)
    return rundate
else:
    app_window.wm_title("Pick1")
    app_window.geometry("250x150+100+100")
    app_window.overrideredirect(False)
    #app_window.mainloop()
    cm = pick1.CalendarFrame(app_window)
    cm.grid()
    app_window.wait_variable(cm.wait_for_result)
    return cm.rundate

rundate = rundate()
print(rundate)
```

and changing the weeklyrpt code to this:

```
# Query permits made effective since rundate
vars = ','.join(['?'] * len(rundate, ))

query = ('''select `NPDES_ID`, `EffectiveDate`, `FacilityName`, `StateFacilityID`, `City`, `CountyName`
        from Permits 
        where `EffectiveDate` IN (%s) 
        order by `NPDES_ID`''' % vars)

IDS=[]
FacCodes=[]
PermStrings=[]
PayStrings=[]
OwnerStrings=[]
MTB=[]
MTG=[]
MTR=[]
count=0
# for each row in result of query
for row in cur.execute(query, (*rundate, )):
```

Thank you again for your help!!